# Java Class in an Eclipse Project shows Error when it is created

Tags: eclipse

Actually, after I created the Project in Eclipse, I created a Java class, but it showed an error:

```
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.
```

[image: Here is the link to the image of the error]

I don't know how to resolve this error.

BTW, I have properly installed JDK v1.8 on my computer.

So, please can anyone resolve this problem?

Comment: Please do not post links to images, put the text code/errors in the question.  To make things worse, your screen shot is hiding the code.  Eclipse shows 6 errors on the problems view.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the used _JRE_. Make sure the JDK is added and selected as default in _Windows > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_. Please add the content of the `.classpath` file to your question (which is not visible in the _Package Explorere_ view, but visible in the _Navigator_ view).

Comment: @OldProgrammer Instead of saying what's bad, say how to do it better (or click _edit_ and improve the question).